# How to make Linux kernel code to be cross-platform?

Tags: linux, kernel

My driver code should support two platforms: one is ARM and another one is X86.
My idea is that define one of CONFIG_ARM_ABC and CONFIG_X86_XYZ in the defconfig file. So the CONFIG_ macros should be in the generated .config file. And in driver source code, I could write the platform specific code as below:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_ARM_ABC
....arm specific code here...
#elif CONFIG_X86_XYZ
...x86 specific code here...
#else
...other platform specific code here...
#endif
```

Is this feasible? Any other idea?
Thanks!

Comment: `Is this feasible?` - We don't know your code, so if it works, than it feasible. But usually architecture-specific code is contained in per-arch directories, so `#ifdef` will not pollute common code, and adding support for new architecture becomes easier.

Comment: It usually doesn't work for arch specific code protected by CONFIG_ARCH_xxx.